# findout index of a tr tag from its specific td tag with selenium in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have a table which is dynamic so I don't know how many tr it'll have.
here is the abstract code:

```
<table id='detail'>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class='multi_row'>Outbound Rail Unloading</td>
    <td class='multi_row'>MONTREAL, QC ,CANADA</td>
    <td class='ico_a'>2018</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='multi_row'>some text</td>
    <td class='multi_row'>some another text</td>
    <td class='ico_a'>2018</td>
  <tr>
    <td class='multi_row'>some text</td>
    <td class='multi_row'>some another text</td>
    <td class='i_e'>2019</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

so i want the index of the last ico_a(the last ico_a in the list shows that where the product is so thats why i need it) which in this example is 1 (it must count from 0). because i need some another datas in this same table i'd rather a solution which gets whole table and iterate on and meanwhile i get some datas like this:

```
event_path = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='detail']//tr/td[2]")
event = [driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', cell).strip() for cell in event_path]

place_path = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='detail']//tr//td[3]")
place = [driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', cell).strip() for cell in place_path]
```

if you have better solution for parsing data from this table i appriciate if you pose it.

Comment: So you are trying to get td[2] value of last td which has class ico_a. Right?

Comment: I'm trying to get the last td[3] with ico_a class in all tr tags actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all td[3] with ico_a class in all tr tag,

```
element= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table//td[3][@class='ico_a']")
elementvalues = [element.text  for element in elements]
```

To get the tr index of  last td with ico_a class,

```
cell=driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//table//td[@class='ico_a'])[last()]/parent::tr")
driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].rowIndex;', cell)
# 1
```

the index start from 0 here

To get the last td with ico_a class,

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//table//td[@class='ico_a'])[last()]").text
# 2018
```

To get the td[2] value of row which contains last td with ico_a class,

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//table//td[@class='ico_a'])[last()]/preceding-sibling::td[1]")).text
# some another text
```

To get the td[1] value of row which contains last td with ico_a class,

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//table//td[@class='ico_a'])[last()]/preceding-sibling::td[1]")).text
# some another text
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.the second code is kinda the thing i want but i want the index of that tr not the 2018 text.sure the first step is to find the last ico_a but index of that tr is the matter

Comment: I have updated that answer to get index option of tr